# R 4.0 using Rtools/ instead of rtools40/

Tags: r, rtools, r-4.0

I recently updated R from 3.6.1 to 4.0.2. Along with that, I updated to the latest version of rtools (rtools40). I also followed instructions to add rtools40 to the PATH [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/).

However, after restarting R, `Sys.which("make")` gives `"C:\\Rtools\\bin\\make.exe"`, an older version of Rtools. But `C:/Rtools/bin` is not in my PATH.

Without deleting the old rtools, how can I tell R to use rtools40?

---

**Edit**: It turns out that the old Rtools was on the system PATH (but not on the user PATH). Removing the old Rtools/ from system PATH fixed the issue.

Comment: One way to do this is to remove the old Rtools from your `PATH`, and then add Rtools40 to your path.

Comment: @mhh Thanks, but the old Rtools is not on my PATH, while rtools40 is. I'm not sure why R is still using the wrong directory to rtools. Any idea?

Comment: @mhh Found it. The old Rtools was not on my user PATH, but on the system PATH. Removing the old Rtools from system PATH fixed the issue. thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @bert! I submitted an answer as well, so that others may more easily find the solution instead of skimming through the comments. Imo, this should be made more clear on the installation page you linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer, so that others may more easily find the solution:

When updating from Rtools to Rtools40, make sure that the old Rtools is removed from the system and user `PATH`. In order to check which version you have in your path, you can use `Sys.which("make")` like you suggested in your question.

It is also possible to check by running `Sys.getenv("PATH")`.